# Reading a list of numbers separated by comma into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have a file of the following form

```
-1,1.2
0.3,1.5
```

Basically a list of vectors, where the dimension of the vectors is known but the number of vectors isn't. I need to read each vector into an array. In other words I need to turn

```
-1,1.2
```

into an array of doubles so that vector[0] == -1 , vector[1] == 1.2

I'm really not sure how to start.

Comment: look at the `strtok`, `fgets`, `scanf` man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three parts to the problem:

- Getting access to the data in the file, i.e. opening it
- Reading the data in the file
- Tidying up, i.e. closing the file

The first and last part is covered in [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) as well as a couple of other things.

The middle bit can be done using formatted input, [here's a example](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/fscanf.html). As long as the input is well formatted, i.e. it is in the format you expect, then this will work OK. If the file has formatting errors in then this becomes trickier and you need to parse the file for formatting errors before converting the data.